# Hessian deserializes java.lang.Character as a String

Tags: java, serialization, hessian

I've used Hessian for a while but just noticed the following behavior.  If you serialize a java.lang.Character in Hessian, it deserializes as a String.

```
public class TestHessianChar {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        // Serialize
        Character c = new Character('x');
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Hessian2Output hessian2Output = new Hessian2Output( byteArrayOutputStream );
        hessian2Output.startMessage();
        hessian2Output.writeObject(c);
        hessian2Output.completeMessage();
        hessian2Output.close();
        byte[] dataBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        // Deserialize
        Hessian2Input hessian2Input = new Hessian2Input( new ByteArrayInputStream(  dataBytes ) );
        hessian2Input.startMessage();
        Object o = hessian2Input.readObject();
        hessian2Input.completeMessage();
        hessian2Input.close();

        System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Output for this code is:

```
java.lang.String
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with language-independent serialization of primitives, but it's rather annoying.  I am writing a JMS driver and need to distinguish between char and String, since the spec demands different behavior.  I'm considering writing my own class to represent a char (and give up auto-boxing), but I wanted to know if there is a proper way to get Hessian to treat a Character as a Character before I start going through such contortions.

Answer (score 0):

The default Hessian serializer transforms characters (either char primitives or objects) into strings, see the source code here:

https://github.com/ebourg/hessian/blob/git-svn/src/com/caucho/hessian/io/BasicSerializer.java#L144

To work around this, you either have to write your own Hessian serializer, or you can use a wrapper object:

```
class CharacterWrapper implements Serializable {
    public Character character;
}

CharacterWrapper cw = new CharacterWrapper();
cw.character = new Character('x');

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Hessian2Output hessian2Output = new Hessian2Output( byteArrayOutputStream );
hessian2Output.startMessage();
hessian2Output.writeObject(cw);
hessian2Output.completeMessage();
hessian2Output.close();
```